# How do you add up the odd positional numbers only in a UPC-12 validator

Tags: python-2.7

I just need ideas on how would i add up the odd positional numbers only. For example, if i had 012345678905, i would only need to add 0, 2,4, 6, 8 etc. What I currently have is basically a module (yet to be completed), and this program is asking me valadiate UPC-12 numbers. Im completly confused, as im not entirely sure what i'm doing. I haven't learned "len" (somthing like that) yet.

```
# Gets the digit of the number using the specified position
def get_digit(number, position):
    return number / (10**position) % 10



     def is_UPC12(number):
            sum_odd = 0
            sum_even = 0

            #loops through the UPC code and checks every odd position and adds the numbers
            for num in range(1, 13, 2):
                sum_odd += get_digit(number, num)   

            sum_odd *= 3

            #loops through the UPC code and checks every even position and adds the numbers
            for num in range(2, 13, 2):
                    sum_of_even += even

            sum_even += get_digit(number, num)      

            Sum = sum_of_odd + sum_of_even_two

            #subtracts 10 from the last digit of the sum, and if it's equal to the last digit of number then it returns True.
            if 10 - get_digit(Sum , 0) == get_digit(number , 0):
                return True
            elif 10 - get_digit(Sum , 0) == 10 and get_digit(number , 0) == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Comment: basically, i have to create a function that validates UPC- 12 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the modulus % operator? Ex. x % 2 = 0 is an even number.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (not necessarily the best) is:

```
# get the number to be tested
test_number = raw_input("Enter number to validate: ")

# set an initial 'sum' value at zero
sum = 0

# iterate through the characters in the input string, only selecting odd position characters
for i in range((len(test_number)+1)/2):
    # a test print statement to check that it's working
    print test_number[i*2]
    # add the value of the character (as int) to 'sum'
    # note that this doesn't deal with exceptions 
          # (if the input is not numeric, it will throw an error)
    sum += int(test_number[i*2])

# get the final sum
print "sum: " + str(sum)
```

EDITED - alternate approach

Another way is:

```
test_number = raw_input("Enter number to validate: ")
sum = 0
odd_numbers = test_number[::2]
for char in odd_numbers:
    sum += int(char)
print "sum: " + str(sum)
```

where "odd_numbers" is a new string composed of the alternate characters from the original string (using the slice method with a step-size of 2).